# Why doesn't Firefox native JSON viewer work for my request?

Tags: json, firefox-addon

I am trying to see a response to my [url](https://auction-sandbox.ea.openprocurement.org/database/11111111111111111111111111110149) in Firefox JSON viewer, but it is always shown as a plain text. I have option `devtools.jsonview.enabled` set to `true`. I send a request with a header `Accept: application/json` and get the response with the 'correct' `content-type:  application/json`. Unfortunately, it does't work with my url.

However, Firefox JSON viewer works pretty well with another url. What is it wrong with this one?

Comment: Are you sure your json is well formated? Try to put them into http://jsonmate.com/ and compare them carefuly.

Comment: Json is valid. Absolutely sure. Here is my link:
https://auction-sandbox.ea.openprocurement.org/database/11111111111111111111111111110149

Answer (score 3):

After some investigations following your example link, and as you said, the json is valid and well formated.

But the server does not send the `application/json` header correctly.

If you can't modify the server, you can still proxy it with the correct header from another server, like this:

Example in php:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$data = file_get_contents("https://auction-sandbox.ea.openprocurement.org/database/11111111111111111111111111110149");
echo $data;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Do you suggest to set up my own server with some scripting language processing the requests, and use it as a proxy server in browser configuration?

Comment: Well, because the json is valid, you are not forced to, this is fine like this to use it with javascript (js just use it as flat text!). Firefox won't parse if the document header isn't well set. The only way to bypass the header, if you are forced to, is to set up a server, or maybe by using a third party api. The example i left is very robust, no worries php is fine for that.

Comment: You can quickly set it like this: `nohup php -S adress:port api &`, where `api` is a file containing the php code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have sudo rights on my working pc and hence cannot install php. Besides, I don't know php. But I caught the idea and will implement such simple server in Python. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I too have this issue and don't have access to change the server.

If you are just trying to view your JSON, like me, try Postman or another browser. My results below.

Firefox developers edition: JSON values as string.

Chrome and Edge: XML.

IE: Downloads JSON

Comment: Seconding the amazing tool Postman. I'm a huge fan and use it all the time to test me API routes.